# How can I get the page or post language when I use wpml?

Tags: php

I'm using [WordPress MultiLanguage Plugin](http://wpml.org/) and I want to know what is the language of a specific element, page or post.

I do have the `id` but I want to obtain the language.

Answer (score 1):

From The WPML website:

http://wpml.org/documentation/support/wpml-coding-api/

```
Language constants

WPML defines the following constants which can be used in the theme:

Constant              Description                                        Example

ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE     Code for the current language                      fr
ICL_LANGUAGE_NAME     Name of current language, in the current language  Français
ICL_LANGUAGE_NAME_EN  Name of the current language name in English       French
```

Comment: It's about page language, not the language supported and i don't need this in the theme, I need this inside a plugin.

Comment: Those constants are defined at priority 1 on the `'plugins_loaded'` action, using the current url's language code. I promise you, that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

To get the language of a specific post or page, you can use `wpml_get_language_information()`. This returns an array with the following indexes:

- locale
- text_direction
- display_name
- native_name
- different_language

**Example**

```
$language_information = wpml_get_language_information($post_id);
$locale = $language_information['locale'];
```

I have found this function via andreas.n on the [WPML Forums](http://wpml.org/forums/topic/how-to-get-the-language-code-for-a-post-id/#post-78967).